# need help joining two tables, sql

Tags: sql, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've searched stackoverflow but could not get an answer to my question.

Table 1 has two columns

1. employee_id
2. employee_name

Table 2 has two columns

1. employee_id
2. Manager_id

Manager_id is a subset of Employee_id, which in turn means that Manager's name will be available in Employee_name list.

How do I join both the tables to get result like : employee_id, Employee_name, Manager name.

My query :

```
SELECT employee_id,
       employee_name,
       manager_id AS manager_name
FROM   table1
       LEFT JOIN table2
              ON table1.employee_id = table2.employee_id
WHERE  manager_id = employee_id;
```

Please , suggest an appropriate approach for this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need a 2nd join. 1st join is from t1 to t2 to get the manager of the employee.  the next join would be from t2 back to t1 again to get the name of the manger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join back to `table1`:

```
select 
    employees.employee_name.employee_id,
    employees.employee_name,
    managers.employee_name as manager_name
from table1 as employees
    left join table2
        on table2.employee_id = employees.employee_id
    left join table1 as managers
        on managers.employee_id = table2.manager_id
```

Additionally, since you're already filtering down to matching managers through the `JOIN` clauses, you can exclude the `WHERE` from your original query.

Answer (score 2):

You need a 2nd join.

- 1st join is from t1 to t2 to get the manager of the employee.
- The next join would be from t2 back to t1 again to get the name of the manger.

I'm assuming you want all employees and the name of the manger if one is defined.

```
SELECT emp.employee_id,
       emp.employee_name,
       mgr.employee_name AS manager_name
FROM   table1 Emp
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
 ON emp.employee_id = t2.employee_id
LEFT JOIN table1 mgr
 on mgr.employee_Id = t2.manager_Id
```

--What's this for?

```
WHERE  manager_id = employee_id;
```

Comment: What is the need of where condition

Comment: you beat me to it, I don't know.

Comment: The where clause would actually break it I think.  It finds employees who manage themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the `WHERE` clause makes sense.  Try taking it out.  That will restrict your results to employees who manage themselves.

Also, please add table aliases.  Even without the where clause, there is ambiguity.

Lastly, a single join just gets you the manager's ID.  To get their name, you need a second join.

```
SELECT emp.employee_id,
       emp.employee_name,
       mgr.employee_name AS manager_name
FROM   table1 emp
       LEFT JOIN table2 map
              ON map.employee_id = emp.employee_id
       LEFT JOIN table1 mgr
              ON mgr.employee_id = map.manager_id
```

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable suggestions and answers. 

+1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try a recursive join using an alias:

```
select a.employee_id, a.employee_name, b.manager_id, c.employee_name as manager_name 
from table1 a
left join table2 b on b.employee_id = a.employee_id 
left Join table1 c on c.employee_id = b.manager_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.employee_id,
       t1.employee_name,
       t2.manager_id AS manager_name
FROM   table1 t1, table2 t2               
WHERE  t2.employee_id = t1.employee_id;
```